# Вращение объекта вокруг центра

Tags: javascript, 3d

Как рассчитать орбиту/сделать вращение объекта вокруг центра в трехмерном пространстве с смещением орбиты на некоторый угол за каждые пол оборота? (изображение приблизительное)

[image]

Comment: Используйте плавающие полярные координаты, например.